# Magento admin css not working

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, css, js-css

I am trying to install site offline which is currently online.

But admin panel coming without css and js.

Any help.

In chrome console I got this

```
Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "https://localhost/venky/admin/".
localhost/:7 Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "https://localhost/venky/admin/".
(index):1Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
(index):1Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
(index):1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
(index):1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
(index):1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
(index):45 Uncaught ReferenceError: varienForm is not defined(anonymous function) @ (index):45
```

I tried 'view page source'

I got code

When I click on css or js links they just reload the page.

In firefox I got this console

```
This site makes use of a SHA-1 Certificate; it's recommended you use certificates with signature algorithms that use hash functions stronger than SHA-1.[Learn More] localhost
The stylesheet https://localhost/venky/admin/ was not loaded because its MIME type, "text/html", is not "text/css".
```

Comment: did you check your console log and also your skin folder has the right permissions?

Comment: do you mean you are trying to install dump of currently live site to other place ? delete var/cache folder

Comment: is frontend working properly?

Comment: I updated my question @ShaheerAli

Comment: I tried deleting var/cache folder Not working @MineshPatel

Comment: Front end working properly @AshishMadankar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an .htaccess file into your root folder (or update the existing one) with this line inside

```
AddType text/css css
```

this will tell apache to send the right content-type header for .css file

**Update**

your are putting `https` in your url . But not configured ssl on localhost. remove s from your url . try like `http:\\localhost\your_store_url`

Comment: Not working @ShaheerAli

Comment: @Jatin you made any more changes to .htaccess file like RewriteRule or some thing else and what is your local sever type and platform ?

Comment: I am using xampp @ShaheerAli

Comment: I updated my question @ShaheerAli

Comment: try to rename your .htaccess file and put default magento .htaccess file @Jatin

Comment: Still not working @ShaheerAli

Comment: why your are putting https. on local you not configure secure ssl certificate remove the s from https and then try again @Jatin

Comment: How can I remove that @ShaheerAli

Comment: put http in  your url  @Jatin

Comment: like "http://localhost/venky/admin/" @Jatin

Answer (score 0):

First check the permission. if all oks then

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM core_config_data WHERE path LIKE '%merge%';
```

You should get two results. Try setting them to 0 if they are enabled, and then remove your /var/ folder to clear cache.

Comment: I tried not working @AshishMadankar

Comment: I updated my question @AshishMadankar